# Why can't VSCode Python linter resolve import of file in the same directory?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint, vscode-python

Take the following folder structure.

```
sidebar-update
    __init__.py
    index.py
    results.py
```

When importing a given function in `index.py` from `results.py` with the statement

```
from results import getResultsTable
```

VSCode produces the following linting problem.

```
unresolved import 'results'Python(unresolved-import)
```

I take this as the linter searching solely for installed modules and ignoring local files. How can I add this functionality so that it recognizes valid import statements?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by enabling jedi and disabling Visual Studio IntelliCode for Python. Apparently it was a language server issue.

Comment: I didn't have Visual Studio IntelliCode installed, but had the same issue.  Disabling Pylance did the trick for me, leaving the MS Python IntelliSense extension enabled.